# Using inverses to find solutions.

Tags: inverse

So upon solving some trigonometric equations, I found myself using the following method often:$$f[g(x)]=h(x)$$$$f[g(g^{-1}(x))]=h[g^{-1}(x)]$$$$f(x)=h[g^{-1}(x)]$$Which is how I usually find $f(x)$ when another function is inside it.

But is there a name for this method and/or anything I should note?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes known as "[precomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback) by $g^{-1}(x).$" As long as the function of $g^{-1}$ *exists*, there's nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: Love how the wikipedia says that this is often "passed over without mention".  Much how I was thinking